# Syntax Error OCaml

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I started writing this in OCaml in order to get a count of each character in a file.

```
open Hashtbl;;

type 'a option = None | Some of 'a;;

let rec charCount fd ht =
  let x = 
    try Some (input_char fd)
    with End_of_file -> None
  in
  match x with
  | Some c -> 
    let val = 
      try find (ht c)
      with Not_found -> 0
    in
    replace ht c (val+1);
    charCount fd ht
  | None -> ();;

let ht = create 0;;

let loadHisto fn = 
  let fd = open_in fn 
  in 
  charCount fd ht;;
  loadHisto "testfile";;
  iter printf("%s => %s\n") ht;;
```

When I try to compile it with `ocamlc -c` I get the message :

`Error: Syntax error:`

Comment: As a side comment, I would advise against opening the `Hashtbl` module in real code. If that was its intended use, its functions would need to have less generic names.

Answer (score 2):

`val` is a reserved word, you can't use it

Comment: But there is another error that I sadly can't understand : "Error : This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type 'a -> 'b"    (lines : 
 Some c -> 
    let val = 
      try find (ht c)
      with Not_found -> 0)

Comment: `find (ht c)` should probably be `find ht c`. `ht` is not a function, and `(ht c)` is a function call to `ht`.